# My Regex is not working all of a sudden?

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex which I am testing to validate my register form, the regex worked perfectly a few days ago and now all of a sudden even if I match the regex in the form which is validated client side and passes (same regex) and then the server side is spitting out the else statement saying I am not matching the regex each time now. Any clues guys?

```
$usern = $_POST['username'];
$regex = '(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{3,}';

$Access = preg_match($regex, $usern);

if($Access) 
{
   //database stuff here
}
else
{
   echo "You filled the form out incorrectly!";
}
```

Comment: Use `$regex = '~^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{3,}~';` - you forgot the delimiters. And an anchor at the start would be a good idea.

Comment: You are a wizard sir, I owe you big time as I was sat there staring at my code puzzled and confused, tried, tested and working thankyou man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue are the missing delimiters, but as best practice, it is also a good idea to add an `^` anchor:

```
$regex = '~^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{3,}~';
```

Validation regexps are usually built with the [principle of contrast](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast) in mind, and your regex is more efficient when you rewrite it like

```
$regex = '~^(?=\D*\d)(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z]).{3,}~';
```

So, the regex will (in)validate the input faster without the redundant backtracking caused by `.*` in the lookaheads.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)). After 15 rep points you are entitles to upvoting on SO.